# update kubernetes ingress helm chart port

Tags: kubernetes, port, kubernetes-helm, nginx-ingress, helm3

How to update Kubernetes ingress helm chart port number to use other than port 80 for all the services
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R7lqy.png)

Thanks

Comment: share your helm chart which one you are using

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your helm chart and values files, it is difficult to tell you exactly which values to update. In your values files you should add something like the following to an ingress section:

```
  hosts:
    - paths:
        - path: /
          pathType: Prefix
          backend:
            service:
              name: {name-of-choice}-service
              port:
                number: {port-of-choice}
```

Comment: You may also be referring to just the services in which case you want to add a values for service port "service:  port: {port-of-choice}"